# Ajax call after changing the value of a 'option' tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I am facing a little problem using ajax.

I need when I change the value of 'select' tag's 'option' then it will call ajax and the value which I get from the ajax call will show in 'input' tag named 't_name'. But its not working. What the problem in my code?How can I solve it? thank you.

Below is my code :

```
        <select id="teacher_select" class="teacher_select" name="teacher_select" value="Select Teacher">
            <option value="">Select Teacher</option>
            <?php
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($teacher) ):
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['t_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['t_name'];?></option>
            <?php 
            endwhile;
            ?>
     </select>

         <input type="text" name="t_credit" id="t_credit"/>
```

Ajax :

```
     $('#teacher_select').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_taken_credit.php',
        data: 't_id='+ $('#teacher_select').val(),                
        success: function(reply_data){
            $('#t_credit').html(reply_data);
          }
        });
     });
```

get_taken_credit.php :

```
         include('db_connection.php'); 
         $t_id = $_POST['t_id'];
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT t_credit FROM teacher WHERE t_id = '$t_id'");
         echo $result;
         exit();
```

Comment: what you mean by not working?

Comment: Your html shows `#dept_select` and your javascript refers to `#teacher_select`. Did you really show us the correct snippet of your code? And: try to replace `$('#t_credit').html(reply_data);` with `$('#t_credit').val(reply_data);`.

Comment: also instead of click event use `change` in dropdown case

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the id is wrong, you call `#teacher_select` instead of `#dept_select`, and try to use

```
$('#dept_select').change(function () {
```

instead of

```
$('#teacher_select').click(function () {
```

Comment: please in english. can't understand @Mi name

Comment: Thanks Ehsan Sajjad, im not speak english